# Liking Facebook Page on behalf of user through SLRequest?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, slrequest

I'm currently using SLRequest to allow the user to like our app page in exchange for virtual currency / new character. What parameters do I need to set to allow this? I already have been granted public_actions permission.

I found the following, but I'm still confused on what to do exactly: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/og.likes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read this [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/og.likes), it says-

> The **`og.likes`** action can refer to any open graph object or URL, except for Facebook Pages or Photos.

So, liking a page with Graph API isn't possible.

I think you have just 2 alternatives-

1. You can load the FB page in the FB application and make the user able to like the page from there.

   ```
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/{page-id}"]];
   ```
2. You can use a `UIWebView` and add a [Like Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/).

You can also check this: [FacebookLikeView](https://github.com/brow/FacebookLikeView)

Comment: Would this require to reauthenticate the user through means other than ACAccountStore, or could I pull in the saved fbAccount that I stored, when asking for permission?

Comment: When did I say you require any additional permissions/re-authentication ? :-/

Comment: I mean assuming I load up a webview with the page url, would the user have to sign in, or would it automatically authenticate them.

Comment: To clarify What I was planning on doing was display a webview have the user like the app page, on dismissal perform a method that checks if user likes the page (using SLRequest) if so reward them. However, I would want to do this in the easiest possible manner.

Comment: I think you can use the [FB.Event.subscribe](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe) to catch the like/dislike event and handle the things accordingly. I've added a git project in the answer you can check

Comment: thank you for your help, I'll definitely have a look!

Comment: +1 for giving the deep-linking approach for fb:// 
However, it would be good to first make a check using UIApplication canOpenURL: API to check whether the user has facebook app open or not, and if not take an appropriate action of either opening in Native Browser using facebook.com instead of fb:// protocol or prompting the user for oAuth.